# Block executed on the member of the collection passed to the partial is executing twice, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The partial code is being rendered with;

```
<%= render: @feed_items %>
```

Where `@feed_items` contains the microposts which gives it a `micropost` variable for each member of the collection in the partial.

_micropost.html.erb

```
<li>
  <div>
    <%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], remote: true, :html => {:class => 'comment_form'}) do |f| %>     
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
      <%= f.submit "post comment" %>
    <% end %>  
  </div>
  <div class="comments_container<%= micropost.id %>">
    <% if micropost.comments.present? %>
      <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="comment">
        <%= comment.content %>
        <%= link_to "Comments posts", micropost_comment_path(micropost, comment), method: :get %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>   
  </div>
</li>
```

The problem is that when the form is inserted the `<% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>` is executing twice. When I remove the form my code works perfectly. I can verify using `<%= comment.inspect %>` inside the block, what is spit out is

```
<div>
#<Comment id: 1, content: "hello", micropost_id: 1809, gallery_id: nil, picture_id: nil, created_at: "2018-05-29 06:53:21", updated_at: "2018-05-29 06:53:21">
</div>
<div>
#<Comment id: nil, content: nil, micropost_id: 1809, gallery_id: nil, picture_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
</div>
```

I can see that there is a value for the second object `micropost_id: 1809` but everything else is nil.

**EDIT**

My question is is that I only have 1 comment for that micropost in the database, which is the first comment in the inspected object, the second is just randomly created and I am not sure why?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry I added it as a edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this changes.

```
<%= form_for([micropost, Comment.new], remote: true, :html => {:class => 'comment_form'}) do |f| %>
```

`micropost.comments.build` is generate new comments belongs to micropost.

So one more comment will be displayed.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks!